# How to correctly configure spring `oauth2Login` with SSL enabled?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure an OAuth2 client with spring-boot, but couldn't configure `oauth2Login()` correctly: when trying to access [`https://localhost:8080`](https://localhost:8080), I keep being redirected to `https://localhost:8443/oauth2/authorization/spring-addons-public` to initiate login, when I'd expect to be first redirected to  [`https://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/spring-addons-public`](https://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/spring-addons-public) (mind the port `8080` which is Spring client's one) which, in turn, should redirect me to `https://localhost:8443/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth` (this is configured `authorization-uri`, `8443` being the port of authorization-server).

If I explicitely visit [`https://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/spring-addons-public`](https://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/spring-addons-public), then authentication-code flow is correctly initiated.

What did I miss?

Simplest reproducer:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          spring-addons-public:
            client-id: "spring-addons-public"
            client-secret: ""
            client-name: "spring-addons-public"
            provider: "keycloak"
            scope: 
              - "openid"
              - "profile"
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            client-authentication-method: "none"
            authorization-grant-type: "authorization_code"

        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: "https://localhost:8443/realms/master"
            authorization-uri: "https://localhost:8443/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
            token-uri: "https://localhost:8443/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain uiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
        http.oauth2Login();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

`src/main/resources/static/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>secured</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Secured</h1>
</body>
```

#### Edit

SSL is enabled by default for my spring-boot apps (I have set `SERVER_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD`, `SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE` and `SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD` environement variables). I figured out that redirections are done to the right port if I explicitely disable SSL with `server.ssl.enabled=false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to force the first redirect port in Java conf:

```java
    http.oauth2Login().loginPage("https://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/spring-addons-public");
```

I still don't understand why, when SSL is enabled on the client, default configuration redirects to the authorization-server socket (instead of the client socket where the default login page is generated).

And it's the same with the post login redirect (after authorization code was sucessfully exchanged for tokens): I am redirected to the authorization-server index when I'd expect to be redirected to client's index.

I opened [a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12307) for that.

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14174